# a4j:commandButton oncomplete not firing

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

We are moving an application to a newer version of RichFaces and JSF (4.2.2 and 2.0 respectively I believe) and I'm trying to make the necessary adjustments to get the app to function like it did before (I don't have a ton of experience with jsf/richfaces).

On one of our pages, when we click a button we need to display a pop-up that says "one moment please..." and when processing is done the pop up needs to go away.  I started out trying something like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="viewEditTop" value="#{SearchBean.mode}"
                        action="#{SearchResultsBean.processSelected}"
                        styleClass="generalButton" onclick="#{rich:component('wait-dialog')}.show()" oncomplete="#{rich:component('wait-dialog')}.hide()"/>
```

But the oncomplete doesn't seem to fire.  The pop-up gets displayed, but never goes away.  After a ton of research and trying various things (mostly trying to call an a4j:status and trying to find details info about how to trigger oncomplete, and statuses and whatnot) I'm at a loss of what to do next.

Does anyone know how to get the oncomplete to fire? or if i'm supposed to be using an a4j:status, how I would get the status to work? I defined the status, added "onstart" and "onstop" to show/hide the pop-up and set my a4j:commandButton status to reference the status i created and it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove the action and add a `console.log('your custom message')` in the "oncomplete" method to check if the action has been invoked. After that, make sure the `SearchResultsBean.processSelected` method doesn't return a String and don't generate any exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll have to look into the string theory a bit.

The processSelected method does return a string.  Why does that cause a problem?  Using the older versions of jsf/richfaces they had an oncomplete method that worked even though processSelected returns a string.

The string it returns is used for navigation that's configured in faces-config.xml (though in the case i'm having trouble with an empty string is returned and i just want the popup to go away instead of navigating to a different page).

Comment: When the navigation is fired, the "oncomplete" method won't fire. For this case, you could use `<a4j:status onstart="#{rich:component('wait-dialog')}.show()" onstop="#{rich:component('wait-dialog')}.hide()" />`, and erase those calls from your `<a4j:commandButton>`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Running into the exact same issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Dave4988, but it turned out that it was caused by an external library we where using.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a4j:commandButton id="viewEditTop" value="#{SearchBean.mode}"
                            action="#{SearchResultsBean.processSelected}"
                            styleClass="generalButton" onbegin="#{rich:component('wait-dialog')}.show()" oncomplete="#{rich:component('wait-dialog')}.hide()"/>
```

you can try this i think it will work 4 u...